# I want to Fetch data from a url and display it in front end. When I did it in postman it was working fine. But in the below JS code I getting an err

Tags: javascript

```
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "X-Auth-Token": 'abc'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    console.log(response.json());
}

postData('url', { answer: 42 });
```

**Error:**
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.
at postData (index.js:3:28)
at index.js:14:1

Comment: What isn't clear about the error message?  A GET request can't have a body.  Did you mean to use a POST request?

Comment: I was able to fetch the data in POSTMAN using GET request

Comment: All that means is Postman doesn't actively restrict this behavior, whereas it appears that `fetch` does.  Bodies in GET requests are non-standard and the behavior is essentially undefined.  Different HTTP clients handle it in different ways.  You could try something other than `fetch`, or just not use a body on a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

As the error pointing out you are using the GET method and you could not add a body to it. If you want to store data I would suggest to use POST

You could read more about the http verbs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

Comment: I was able to fetch the data in POSTMAN using GET request

Comment: If you just want to fetch data you don't need a body. But your function called "postData" so that indicates that you want to store a value and therefore you would use POST